# Creating URNs based on a row ID

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataset that has rows with the same Site ID. I want to create a new ID for each row. Currently I have a df like this:

```
SiteID  SomeData1 SomeData2
100001   20        30
100001   20        30
100002   30        40
```

I am looking to achieve the below output

Output:

```
SiteID  SomeData1 SomeData2 Site_ID2
100001   20        30        1000011
100001   20        30        1000012
100002   30        40        1000021
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Add helper `Series` by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) converted to strings to column `SiteID` :

```
s = df.groupby(['SomeData1','SomeData2']).cumcount().add(1)
df['Site_ID2'] = df['SiteID'].astype(str).add(s.astype(str))
print (df)
   SiteID  SomeData1  SomeData2 Site_ID2
0  100001         20         30  1000011
1  100001         20         30  1000012
2  100002         30         40  1000021
```

Comment: @Sloth87 - Thanks, glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it suits you! :)